# does mongoose support virtual fields in select like SQL

Tags: sql, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In SQL I can make the following SELECT statement with the 'status' virtual field:

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN field = 1 THEN 'sale'
      ELSE 'none'
   END as status
```

Does something like is in mongoose?

Comment: MongoDB in general does not as such I would think the answer is no unless mongoose somehow implements it client side.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Mongoose schemas support virtuals. Have a look at the schema section of the [guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html). I think you may want something like this:

```
var salesSchema = new Schema({
  sale: Number
});

salesSchema.virtual('status').get(function() {
  if (this.sale === 1) {
    return 'sale';
  } else {
    return 'none';
  }
});
```

Comment: Though that's actually a stored field on the schema is it not? The SQL version allows you to, in query, create virtual fields derived from other fields values on the fly.

Comment: Is it not stored to the database, that's why they call it a virtual. :)

Comment: Ah ok I see it now, though I stand by my first comment you can't use that field in the query like: `select field+fieldb as fieldc where fieldc = 1` I've got a nasty feeling that's gonna be his next question :)

Comment: are you wanting to do sales.find({status: 'sale'}) ?