# Mongoose temporary calculated field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

For a basic example I have a schema:

```
var testSchema = new Schema({
  op1    : Number,
  op2     : Number
});
```

then I want to have a "total" field that's not stored in DB but automatically computed after retrieval, and possibly can be used for Mongoose's query.sort.

I.e.

```
total = op1 + op2
```

then use `myTestModel.find({}).sort(total).execFind(...);`

Is this possible?

Comment: Virtual fields are easy with Mongoose: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12982125/95190

Comment: Sorting however is not: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13453207/95190. You'd need to do that yourself.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Thanks! Those two references are perfect.

Comment: @WiredPrairie why not add it as an answer so we can upvote you?

Comment: @starquake - the answers were already there. Should have been closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't allow you to calculate fields with normal queries, however, you can do this with the aggregation framework. You'd do that like this:

```
myTestModel.aggregate(
    { $match: {} }, // your find query
    { $project: {
        op1: 1, // original fields
        op2: 1,
        total: { $add: ['$op1', '$op2' ] } // calculated field
    } },
    { $sort: { total: 1 } },

    // And then the normal Mongoose stuff:
    function (err, res) {
    }
);
```

See also: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate

Comment: Thank you. Would you know if there's a performance advantage of using this over the usual .sort javascript function?

Comment: No sorry, you'll have to benchmark that in your own environment. I expect it to be faster as it's run in the database in C++ - and not javascript.